# TypeError when Mocking a Node Module with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, nodemailer, mailgun

Here I have a file, mail.js, that sends an email

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const mailGun = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport')

const auth = {
    auth: {
        api_key: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY,
        domain: process.env.DOMAIN
    }
}

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mailGun(auth))

const mailTo = (name, email) => {
    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'example@icloud.com',
        to: 'cm@example.com',
        subject: 'Welcome!',
        text: `Hey, ${name}! Thanks for joining Task Manager!`
    }
    
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
}

module.exports = mailTo
```

I am trying to do Jest tests and I need to mock the nodemailer and mailGun functions so I don't get an email every time I run a test. So I made a `__mocks__` folder and put my 2 mock modules in it at `__mocks__/nodemailer.js` and `__mocks__/nodemailer-mailgun-transport.js`. Here are those files

```
//nodemailer.js
module.exports = {
    createTransport() {

    },
    sendMail() {

    }
}
```

```
//nodemailer-mailgun-transport.js
module.exports = {
    mailGun() {

    }
}
```

And here are my tests

```
const request = require('supertest')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = require('../src/app')
const User = require('../src/models/user')

const userOneId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
const userOne = {
    _id: userOneId,
    name: 'Jon',
    email: 'jon@example.com',
    password: 'JonTest123',
    tokens: [{
        token: jwt.sign({ _id: userOneId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
    }]
}

beforeEach(async () => {
    await User.deleteMany()
    await new User(userOne).save()
})

test('Should signup a new user', async() => {
    const response = await request(app).post('/users').send({
        name: 'Caleb',
        email: 'caleb@example.com',
        password: 'TestPass637!'
    }).expect(201)

    //Assert that the database was changed correctly
    const user = await User.findById(response.body.user._id)
    expect(user).not.toBeNull()

    //Assertions about the response
    expect(response.body).toMatchObject({
        user: {
            name: 'Caleb',
            email: 'caleb@example.com'
        },
        token: user.tokens[0].token
    })
    expect(user.password).not.toBe('TestPass637!')
})
```

And I have Jest setup to look for the `__mocks__` file in the tests directory, which is where I have it

But when I run my tests, I get
`TypeError: mailGun is not a function`
Why doesn't it recognize the mailGun() function?

Comment: You didn't post your tests. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and specify the hierarchy for files that you posted. If `__mocks__` is in a wrong place, it obviously will be ignored.

Comment: I updated my question. And I do have my ```__mocks__``` directory in the correct spot. If I had it in the wrong spot it would tell me it can't find the ```__mocks__``` directory

Comment: No, it wouldn't tell it. If there were an auto-mock with jest.mock and there were no `__mocks__`, it would just stub the module, that's the most common problem with `__mocks__`. Any way, this is not your case, the problem is that nodemailer-mailgun-transport exports a function and you mocked it with a an object that has mailGun method.

Comment: So what is the correct way to do it? I thought ```module.exports = { mailGun() {} }``` would  mock nodemailer-mailgun-transport with a function.

Comment: `typeof { mailGun() {} } === 'object'`. That you named it mailGun on import is not important, this name doesn't need to appear anywhere.  It should be `module.exports = jest.fn()`.

Comment: I put the ```module.exports = jest.fn()``` in my nodemailer-mailgun-transport.js file. I got the error ```expected 201 "Created", got 400 "Bad Request"```. This error would come from my /users post method. I have try/catch set up. So it appears it tried to send the email and got a 400 error back

Comment: I’m not sure but I think the problem is that sendMail() is not a direct method off of nodemailer, so when I tried to mock it, it didn’t actually mock it and it’s trying to run with its usual data which it no longer has

Comment: Yes, it is. Mock createTransport to return transport object.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm super new to Jest, so I don't entirely know what you're asking me to do. Do I create a createTransport.js file in ```__mocks__``` and put ```module.exports = jest.fn()``` inside, or do something else?

Comment: I mean that createTransport function should be mocked to return an object because it's expected to. Don't do this with plain JS functions like you did, use Jest spies because they can beneficial in several ways, e.g. `module.exports = { createTransport: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({  sendMail: jest.fn() }), ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

The `nodemailer-mailgun-transport` should return a function so that you can pass the `auth` to it. In your test code `mailGun` refers to the default output, not a property.

```
//nodemailer-mailgun-transport.js
module.exports = (auth) => {
  // do something with auth, if you want
}
```